# Does $\phi: A \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to B \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ surj. imply that for $b \in B$, $b = n \phi(a)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a \in A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, abelian-groups

Let $A$ and $B$ be abelian groups. Suppose that we have a morphism $\phi: A \to B$ and that $\phi \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}: A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} \to B \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$ is surjective.

> Is it true that for any $b \in B$, there exists some $n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}$ and some $a \in A$ such that $\phi(a) = n b$?

Comment: Yes. Start by looking at the preimage $\left( \phi \otimes \mathbb{Q} \right)^{-1}(b)$.

Comment: I tried, but I'm stuck. Any further hint?

Comment: What did you get when you tried?